# Counting Parent on nested attributes rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `enrollment.rb`

```
attr_accessible :semester_id
has_many :studentpayments
has_many :student_deductions
```

My `studentpayment.rb`

```
belongs_to :enrollment
```

My `student_deduction.rb`

```
belongs_to :enrollment
```

How do I get the unique enrollment base on `semester_id` and if the `enrollment` has `studentpayment` or has `student_deduction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@enrollment = Enrollment.find_by_semester_id(id) # find by semester_id

@enrollment.studentpayments.any? # if @enrollment has any student payments
@enrollment.student_deductions.any?
```